# the client detail template in kendo UI is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have a kendo grid in an asp .net MVC application. Im following the demos on the kendoui website to build a detail template on my grid. I couldnt make it work. Here's my code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIMvcApplication2.Models.GetCallDetailResult>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.contactCommunicationCallID).Title("CCCID").Width("20");
        columns.Bound(p => p.LocalStartDateTime).Title("Date Time").Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}");
        columns.Bound(p => p.LPEmployeeCode).Title("Employee Code").Width("50");
        columns.Bound(p => p.AdSource).Title("Ad Source");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Status);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Duration).Title("Duration");
        columns.Bound(p => p.TrackingPhoneNumber).Title("Tracking Number");
        columns.Bound(p => p.CallerNumber).Title("Caller Number");
        columns.Bound(p => p.RegionName).Title("Region Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.DistrictName).Title("District Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.CampaignName).Title("Campaign Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.AdSourceCategoryName).Title("Ad Source Category");

    })
.Pageable(page => page.Enabled(true).PageSizes(new Int32[] { 5, 10, 20, 40 }))
.Sortable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 700px" })
.Scrollable()
.ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(5)
    .Read(read => read.Action("CallDetail", "Home"))
)
.Events(ev => ev.DataBound("dataBound"))
```

)

```
<script>
function dataBound() {
    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
}
</script>

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
  @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabStrip_#=contactCommunicationCallID#")
        .SelectedIndex(0)
        .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
        .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text("Details").Content(@<text>
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIMvcApplication2.Models.GetCallDetailResult>()
                    .Name("grid_#=contactCommunicationCallID#")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.contactCommunicationCallID).Title("ID").Width(56);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.SiteName).Width(110);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.LPFirstName);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.LPLastName).Width(190);
                    })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .PageSize(5)
                        .Read(read => read.Action("ReportList", "Home", new { CCCID = "#=contactCommunicationCallID#" }))
                    )
                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .ToClientTemplate()
                 )
            </text>                        
            );
            items.Add().Text("Contact Information").Content(
                "<div class='employee-details'>" +
                    "<ul>" +
                        "<li><label>Country:</label>#= contactCommunicationCallID #</li>" +
                        "<li><label>City:</label>#= SiteName #</li>" +
                        "<li><label>Address:</label>#= LPFirstName #</li>" +
                        "<li><label>Home Phone:</label>#= LPLastName #</li>" +
                    "</ul>" +
                "</div>"
            );                
        })
        .ToClientTemplate())
</script>

<script>
function dataBound() {
    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
}
</script>
```

### Controller Action Methods:

```
    public ActionResult CallDetail([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var readcalldetails = new DataDataContext().GetCallDetail(1, 762, 1).ToList();
        var result = readcalldetails.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result); 
    }

    public ActionResult ReportList(int CCCID, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var readreportlist = new DataDataContext().GetCallDetail(1, 762, 1).ToList().Where(cd => cd.contactCommunicationCallID == CCCID);
        var result = readreportlist.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result);
            //.Where(cd => cd.ContactCommunicationCallID == CCCID)
    }
```

Comment: does your model returns all properties that you have used in Keno Template? those are case sensitive. Make sure you have spelled it right.

Comment: yes it does. as far as i know, the code is good. but im not getting any output. when i debug in IE its showing an invalid template exception and an empty grid.

Comment: start troubleshooting by removing grid code between @<text>  and <text> see if this loads perfectly then you can add grid code in it

Comment: i need to remove this line of code from web.config file.     <!--<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />-->
and it worked! i dont know why but it did. but thx for the help.

Comment: see http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/grid/master-details-grid-not-working.aspx  for more info about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found out by trial and error that the only thing you need to remove from your web.config is the `targetFramework="xx"` portion from the httpRuntime - you can keep the `encoderType` portion!